# Jackson CSV. Quote escaping in headers

Tags: java, csv, jackson, jackson-dataformat-csv

I have a CSV file in which one of the headers looks like  `Name;Lastname;"Some info\n more info"`

My parser:

```
        CsvMapper csvMapper = new CsvMapper();
        CsvSchema csvSchema = CsvSchema.emptySchema()
                .withHeader()
                .withColumnSeparator(';');
            MappingIterator<Map<String, String>> mappingIterator = csvMapper
                    .readerFor(Map.class)
                    .with(csvSchema)
                    .readValues(new InputStreamReader(
                            new FileInputStream("myFilePath"),
                            Charset.forName("windows-1250")
                    ));
```

But after parsing, I lose the quotes in the header and get just `Name;Lastname;Some info\n more info`. How can I save quotes?

Comment: Without reading almost anything from your parser, I would say that the quickest solution would be to add those quotes at the very end of your parser. You parse everything, and at the end, you just go to the specific key and add quotes. Does this solve your problem?

Comment: Not all headers must have quote. Updated the question

Comment: Are you able to edit that .csv before the parsing occurs? If so, can you escape the quotes so you end up with a header like `Name;Lastname;\"Some info\n more info\"` and then parse it?

Comment: No. I can't edit source files